# SES on node.js not sending the email although it return 'success' response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I tried sending an email using SES. The to address is same as the from address, and is verified in AWS SES.

```
        usersList = [{
            "Destination": {
                "ToAddresses": [
                    "someuserthatisverifiedinSES@abc.xyz"
                ]
            },
            "ReplacementTemplateData": `{ "name":"User1", "message": "Hell no" }`
        }];
        defaultTemplateData = `{ "name":"Student", "message": ` + req.body.message + ` }`;

        var params = {
            Destinations: usersList,
            Source: "someuserthatisverifiedinSES@abc.xyz", /* required */
            Template: `SomeTemplate`, /* required */
            DefaultTemplateData: defaultTemplateData
        };
        // Create the promise and SES service object
        var sendPromise = ses.sendBulkTemplatedEmail(params).promise();

        // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
        return sendPromise.then(
            function (data) {
                console.log('sent successfully');
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }).catch(
            function (err) {
                console.log('error happened off');
                console.error(err, err.stack);
                return err;
            });
    }
```

I'm getting a successful response to this code.

> { ResponseMetadata: { RequestId:
>   '14ada23f-someID-5be700be687f' },   Status:     [ { Status:
>   'Success',
>          MessageId: '010001619e8a79ed-someID-000000' } ] }

But the email is not being delivered.

Comment: checked the spam folder?

Comment: @zabusa Junk mail is empty.

Comment: In gmail they could be inside "promotions" folder

Comment: Checked them all. It's in mbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I figured out, the email returns success although it didn't send when the template you created doesn't match the dataset yours sending. Maybe the template has a variable that isn't being addressed by the dataset you give it.

The return value will still be a success which it shouldn't. Upon fixing that bit, I started to receive emails. SES emails don't go to the junk too easily.

Comment: You hit the nail right on the head. Thank you! Saved me an evening of trouble.

Comment: Thank you, this also saved me a massive headache